# trying to convert mysql select statement to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to convert from an old MySQL library to PDO.

In order to read the data with my old MySQL code I use:

$assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeqr);

With PDO I'm trying to do that with a `foreach` like I have on my code using PDO, but its not working...

Can you see something wrong here??

**My OLD ode using MySQL:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
{
    $f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $f['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if(!$f['email'] || !valMail($f['email']))  
    {
      echo 'Email empty or invalid';
    }
    else if(strlen($f['pass']) <8 || strlen($f['pass'])>12)
    {
        echo 'pass must have between 8 and 12 chars!';
    }
    else
    {
        $autEmail = $f['email'];
        $autpass = $f['pass'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users where email= '$autEmail'";       
        $exeqr = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeqr);

        if(mysql_num_rows($exeqr) == 1 )
        {
            if($autEmail == $assoc['email'] && $autpass == $assoc['pass'])
            {
                $_SESSION['assoc'] = $assoc;
                header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }
            else
            {
                echo ' wrong password';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'email does no exist';
        }
    }
}
```

And the new code I am trying to convert using PDO:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
{
    $f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $f['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if(!$f['email'] || !valMail($f['email']))  
    {
        echo 'Email empty or invalid';
    }
    else if(strlen($f['pass']) <8 || strlen($f['pass'])>12)
    {
        echo 'pass must have between 8 and 12 chars!';
    }
    else
    {
        $autEmail = $f['email'];
        $autpass = $f['pass'];
        $searchEmail = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email=:email");   
        $searchEmail->bindValue(":email,$autEmail");   
        $searchEmail->execute; 
        $num_rows = $searchEmail->fetchColumn();
       $result = $searchEmail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        if($num_rows == 1)
        {
            if($autEmail == $result['email'] && $autpass == $result['pass'])
            {
                $_SESSION['result'] = $result;
                header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }
            else
            {
                echo ' wrong password';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'email does no exist';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in $searchEmail->bindValue(":email,$autEmail");**

You need to move your `"`, currently it's including the variable as well as the parameter name resulting in you not passing in the variable to bind to said parameter (which is why you are getting the error telling you you haven't passed in enough arguments).

```
$searchEmail = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = :email");   
$searchEmail->bindValue(":email", $autEmail);
```

> **Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute in $searchEmail->execute;**

You've forgotten the `()` brackets from `execute()`, so PHP is looking for the property of the PDO class called `execute` instead of the function call.

```
$searchEmail->execute();
```

(thanks Prix)

> **Edit**

Your question is now about how to replace this:

```
$assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeqr);
```

... with a PDO equivalent. [In the manual, there is an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples):

```
$assoc = $searchEmail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

**Note:** `fetchAll()` is for fetching multiple results. If you're expecting only one result (which you might be, but you aren't limiting your query so it's feasible to return multiple results), you should just use `fetch()`:

```
$assoc = $searchEmail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you! BUt I have still have this: Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute in $searchEmail->execute;

Comment: I guess is $searchEmail->execute();

Comment: Thank you, can you see if this method with foreach its correct? Because I dont have that erros but when I put the correct email and password it appears my echo 'email does no exist';

Comment: @John23 you should not need any loops since you want to retrieve a single result only. `$result = $searchEmail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); echo $result->email, " - " $result->pass, "\n";` And you should avoid keeping the password on the session, if another user takes that session he will be able to take over that user so you should keep the password out and ask for password depending on the gravity of the action the user requested.

Comment: But I need to acess my user fields like I did with mysql_fectch_assoc($exeqr), so I thought with foreach was a good solution but its not working!

Comment: Just unset the password part of your results before you assign it to the session. As @Prix said, not a good idea, absolutely no need and a big security risk to be storing passwords in sessions. Comparing the PHP email variable to the database result is pointless too as you have used it to select MySQL data already. You may as well bind your password into the original query and do it all in one go (unless you are using a complicated password hashing algorithm that MySQL doesn't support).

Comment: Thanks for your tips but for now I´m just trying to solve the problem because is giving me "headaches" and then I´ll think about security! I update my code using PDO with your result tip but its happening the same, I´m always getting the message "Emails does not exist". But Im putting the correct email, and with old sql its working!

Comment: You changed `FETCH_OBJ` to `FETCH_ASSOC`?

Comment: Now it works...thank you for your help! What I had wrong was the method that I was counting rows! Relatively to the security, I´m storing the password in session because I have this to control the session:  if(!empty($_SESSION['result'])) { header('Location: index2.php'); } . But in your opinion in the session should only store the email/username?

Comment: Yep, no need to store the password there too.

Comment: Ok..I update my code to $_SESSION['result'] = $result['email']; to only store the email. Thank you for your tip :)